# How to mock nested methods using PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock, easymock

Assume I have two classes A and B.

```
Class A{
  public String methodA(String name) {
    B b = new B();
    b.methodB(name);
  }
}

Class B{
   public String methodB(String name) {
        return name+name;
   }
}
```

Now I want to mock methodA which has a nested method call to Class B.I have tried writing the below TestCase but getting **methodNotImplementedException**.

```
@Test  
public void testCase() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = PowerMock.createPartialMock(B.class, "methodB");
  EasyMock.expect(b.methodB(anyString())).andReturn("HELLO PTR");
  PowerMock.replayAll();
  String result = a.methodA("hello ptr");
  assertEquals(result, "HELLO PTRHELLO PTR");
  PowerMock.verifyAll();
}
```

Can anybody tell how to solve nested method calls using PowerMock..??
 Thanx in advance

Comment: What are *nested methods*?

Comment: You are using power mock and easy mock ??

Comment: _Now I want to mock methodA_ - if methodA() is mocked then there's no need to mock b.methodB().

Comment: It is ok to use multiple test frameworks but easy mock is awful. I would suggest using Powermock and mockito in your project. Use powermock for mocking the creation of new objects and  mocking static and final methods. Use mockito for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here.

First, don't use two mocking frameworks at the same time. There's no reason to expect when creating expectations in one framework, that the other would know about it.

Second, if, as stated, you want to mock `methodA`, supposedly as a part of a test of something that uses `A`, then there's no reason to mock anything from `B`, since the result of `methodA` is mocked, and will not invoke `B`.

Third, [mock roles, not objects](http://www.jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf). Meaning, if object `C` accepts an `A`, it shouldn't get the concrete implementation, instead it should get the interface it uses. Then in the test, you mock that interface, not a class.

Given these, if you create an interface for `A`, and stub the response from that interface, your test will be much simpler, and you won't have to resort to these kinds of tools.

Comment: EasyMock and PowerMock are used together. It's the normal way to use them. Nothing wrongs there.

Comment: The fact that you *can* use them together, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: There are meant to be used together. PowerMock isn't supposed to be used by itself. However, I recommend to never use PowerMock except in extreme cases. Because requiring it means a bad design. But, of course, sometime, you are stuck with a bad design. And a tested bad design is better than a bad design

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal by doing the following. Notice the whenNew call

```
@Test  
public void testCase() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = PowerMock.createPartialMock(B.class, "methodB");
  EasyMock.expect(b.methodB(anyString())).andReturn("HELLO PTR");
  PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(b);
  PowerMock.replay(B.class);
  String result = a.methodA("hello ptr");
  assertEquals(result, "HELLO PTRHELLO PTR");
  PowerMock.verifyAll();
}
```

you will also need to add `@PrepareForTest(B.class)` to the test class

Finally, you will need to add the api dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also, I would re-evaluate using eassy mock. Just use the powermockito api in powermock

Comment: Tried your code but I am getting "NoClassDefFoundError".

Comment: Can you give me the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry that code is for the powermockito api. You will need to add the easymock api for powermock. I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock `methodA` then there is no need to do anything with class B. Just do

```
@Test
public void testCase() {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    expect(a.methodA()).andReturn("HELLO");
    replay(a);
    // use the mock to test something
    String result = a.methodA("hello ptr");
    assertEquals(result, "HELLO");
    verify(a);
}
```

But it looks like you want to test A and mock B. That's different. First, I would recommend refactoring. Even a really basic one like

```
public class A{
    public String methodA(String name) {
        B b = newB();
        b.methodB(name);
    }

    protected B newB() {
        return new B()
    }
}
```

That way, you won't need PowerMock at all. You can do

```
@Test
public void testCase() {
    A a = partialMockBuilder().addMockedMethod("newB").mock(A.class);
    B b = mock(B.class);
    expect(a.newB()).andReturn(b);
    expect(b.methodB()).andReturn("HELLO");
    replay(a, b);        

    String result = a.methodA("HI");
    assertEquals(result, "HELLO");

    verify(a, b);
}
```

And then, if you really need for some weird reason to mock `new B()`, yes, using `Powermock.expectNew` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding `PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(b);`  and `@Mock`  annotation in the Test Class`

Complete Code;

```
public class A {
    public String methodA(String name) {
        B b = new B();
        return b.methodB(name);
    }
}

public class B{
    public String methodB(String name) {
        return name+name;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ A.class, B.class })
public class TestCase {

    @Mock
    private B b;

    @Test  
    public void testCase() throws Exception {
       A a = new A();
       PowerMock.expectNew(B.class).andReturn(b);
       EasyMock.expect(b.methodB(anyString())).andReturn("HELLO");
       PowerMock.replay(B.class, b);
       String result = a.methodA("HI");
       assertTrue(result != null);
       assertEquals(result, "HELLO");
       PowerMock.verify(B.class, b);
    }
}
```